# error: variable-sized object may not be initialized|

Tags: c

My code as bellow:

```
const size_t NUM_P = 100;
int main (viod)
{
   char *pS[NUM_P] = { NULL};            /* Array of string pointer */
   /* Other code */
}
```

My compiler is CODEBLOCK, the error will be clear when NUM_P is changed to digits, such as "12,or 35 ..", I don't know the root cause of the error , or it is my compiler problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The root of your problem is that `NUM_P` is a variable, even if it is a `const` one.

Replace its declaration by `#define NUM_P 100` and your code will compile again.

Answer (score 1):

In C you are not allowed to provide an initializer for VLAs.

I'd suggest using a compile-time constant for the array dimension; then it is not a VLA:

```
#define NUM_P 100

int main(void)
{  
    char *pS[NUM_P] = { 0 };
}
```

For historical reasons, a `const` variable is not considered to be a constant expression in C.

Comment: OK,it means that a const variable is still variable, but we need a constant?

Answer (score 0):

That's valid in C++ but not in C. You can use a preprocessor symbol to do that in C.

```
#define NUM_P 100
int main (viod)
{
   char *pS[NUM_P] = { NULL};
}
```